# map<string, int> get rest of map (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm trying to recursively get all the values (and keys) of a `std::map<string, int>` in C++.

By `aMap.begin()->first`, I get the key of the first element.

By `aMap.begin()->second`, I get the value of the first element.

Is there a way to get a map that excludes the first value (already used) in the map? The `aMap.erase(aMap.begin())` is giving me the error: (rest of map)

```
Invalid arguments '
Candidates are:
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> mapToCode(std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,int,std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>,std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>,int>>>)
'
```

Am I not understanding some basic functionalities of C++ standard map?

Here is the function I'm working with:

```
using std::map;
string mapToCode(map<string, int> aMap) {
    string returnString = "Dict(";
    if (aMap.empty()) {
        return returnString + ")";
    } else {
        string hold = mapToCode(aMap.erase(aMap.begin())) + "\"" + aMap.begin()->first + "\", " + std::to_string(aMap.begin()->second) + ")";
        return returnString + hold;
    }
}
```

This is the class that's using it:

```
Dictionary::Dictionary() {
}

Dictionary::Dictionary(Dictionary dicObject, string key, int value) {
    std::map<string, int> newDict;
    newDict[key] = value;
    newDict.insert(dict.begin(), dict.end());

    dict = newDict;
}

string Dictionary::toCode() {
    if (empty()) {
        return "Dictionary()";
    } else {
        return mapToCode(dict);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce the error](https://godbolt.org/z/sfpB47). Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you please post your full code? This code should work just fine. map.erase(map.begin()); There might be something else wrong with your code.

Comment: I'm using a map to make a Dictionary like object. This is a helper function that takes in the map and returns a string that can be "copied" as code to create a duplicate of the same object before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not actually sure what you are trying to achieve so I don't know the order to traverse the map :P But I guess this is somewhat close to what you want:

```
std::string mapToCode(const std::map<std::string, int>& map, std::map<string, int>::iterator it) 
{
    std::string returnString = "Dict(";
    if (it == std::end(map))
    {
        // Not sure if you really wanted to return returnString + ")";
        return ""; // returnString;
    }

    std::string hold = mapToCode(map, std::next(it)) + "\"" + it->first + "\", " + std::to_string(it->second) + ")";
    return returnString + hold;
}
```

Tested this on this input:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> map;

    map.insert(std::make_pair("a", 1));
    map.insert(std::make_pair("b", 2));

    std::cout << mapToCode(map, map.begin()) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Dict(Dict("b", 2)"a", 1)
```

Notes:
Instead of erasing, which might be expensive, we can use the standard library's std::next to move the iterator to the next place in the container :)

Prefer using std before each call to the standard library and avoid using namespace std.

Notice the const& instead of passing the map by value. It prevents copying the entire map.

For the second part regarding copy constructors:

```
Dictionary::Dictionary(const Dictionary& other)
{
    // I am assuming that dict is the class variable that you use to store the actual map in the class

    // Also this "appends" to the existing dictionary
    // If you want to first delete the old one's data, clear the dict
    // dict.clear()
    dict.insert(other.begin(), other.end());
}
```

Comment: Do you know what I'm doing wrong with?
`Dictionary::Dictionary(Dictionary dicObject, string key, int value) {
  std::map<string, int> newDict;
  newDict[key] = value;
  newDict.insert(dict.begin(), dict.end());

  dict = newDict;
 }` Sorry, this should work, but I think my constructor is wrong

Comment: Are you trying to declare a copy constructor? Just explain what you are trying to do. And if possible edit your main question and post your code there.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
string hold = mapToCode(aMap.erase(aMap.begin())) + "\"" + aMap.begin()->first + "\", " + std::to_string(aMap.begin()->second) + ")";
```

doesn't work, because the output of `erase()` is not the modified `map`, like you are expecting.  And even if it did, you would be accessing `aMap.begin()` after `aMap.erase()` modified `aMap`, which will fail after the last element has been erased. You would need something more like this instead:

```cpp
string hold = "\"" + aMap.begin()->first + "\", " + std::to_string(aMap.begin()->second) + ")";
aMap.erase(aMap.begin());
hold = mapToCode(tmp) + hold;
```

But, why are you using recursion at all? An iterative loop would suffice instead:

```cpp
string mapToCode(const map<string, int> &aMap) {
    string returnString = "Dict(";
    if (!aMap.empty()) {
        auto toStr = [](const std::pair<const string, int> &aElement) {
            return "[\"" + aElement.first + "\", " + std::to_string(aElement.second) + "]";
        };
        auto iter = aMap.begin();
        returnString += toStr(*iter);
        while (++iter != aMap.end()) {
            returnString += "," + toStr(*iter);
        }
    }
    return returnString + ")";
}
```